# Dynamically setting the options for an ActionSheet in Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

I am making a GET request to get back some JSON containing an array of options. Within each element I have an id, style and a name.

Based on the response I would like to dynamically set the options of my ActionSheet in my Ionic 2 app.

This ActionSheet works fine. My challenge is setting the options dynamically based on the API response.

```
let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
 title: 'Change the tag of this visitor',
 buttons: [
   {
     text: 'Destructive red',
     cssClass: 'label-red',
     handler: () => {
       myFunction(1);
     }
   },
   {
     text: 'Archive blue',
     cssClass: 'label-dark-blue',
     handler: () => {
       myFunction(2);
     }
   },
   {
     text: 'Cancel',
     role: 'cancel',
     handler: () => {
       console.log('Cancel clicked');
     }
   }
 ]
});
```

I would like the keep the cancel option but show my own options above -- i.e. remove the destructive and archive options.

In PHP I would achieve this with this pseudo code ..

```
$options = array();
$options['title'] = 'Change the tag of this visitor';

$buttons = array();

foreach($api_response as $a) {
    array_push($buttons, array('text' => $a['name'], 'cssClass' => $a['style']) );
}

$options['buttons'] = $buttons;

let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create(json_encode($options));
```

And then my final question is how I can specify the appropriate value of id from the elements that I am looping through as the parameter for the myFunction() call ... e.g set the value of XX to be 1 when id=1, 20 when id=20, etc

e.g.

```
 text: 'Name goes here',
 cssClass: 'label-red',
 handler: () => {
   myFunction(XX);
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to have found a better way to solve this problem. I am using the addButton method ..

```
let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
    title: 'Change the tag of this visitor'
});    

this.http.get('http://api.domain.com/tags', {headers:headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.res.length; i++) {
        actionSheet.addButton({text: data.res[i].name, cssClass: data.res[i].style });        
    }
}); 

actionSheet.addButton({text: 'Cancel', 'role': 'cancel' });       

actionSheet.present();
```

Comment: How can you manage the function triggered at each button of the actionSheet ?

Comment: Hi. Like this ... `actionSheet.addButton({text: 'Go to dashboard', handler: () => { this.navCtrl.setRoot(ListTeamsPage); } }); `

Comment: How about triggering the handler depending upon the element from an array. According to your example, how can I have click event which depends upon data.res[i].index (assume index is unique for each iterations) value.